# How to set the templates directory in Django?

Tags: django, settings

How to define a directory for storing all templates of my app? I am having a hard time finding the explanation how to set templates directory in Django `settings.py` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set your path to templates folder you need to set your DIRS key with the value in which you are giving your path to templates as shown in the example below where at first i am setting a variable TEMPLATES_DIR where BASE_DIR give me the path to the folder where my manage.py is being kept and i concatinate projects directory alongwith templates directory because in my case i kept it inside project directory.

For example :-

```
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project','templates')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

So, Here's the explaination What i did is set the TEMPLATES_DIR variable with reference to base directory that will take the path to folder where manage.py of your django project is being kept now i am concatinating the projects and templates directory just to navigate the exact folder structure that you kept for your templates in your project.

I hope you found this helpful. if you have any more doubts i'll be happy to answer those also.

Happy Coding. :-)

Comment: let me know if you want further explanation :-)

Answer (score 2):

The way to set your templates directory in Django is by setting the value of the `'DIRS'` key in `TEMPLATES` inside the *settings.py* like so (assuming it is present just inside your base directory (`BASE_DIR`):

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

In Django 3, the templates directory can be added to `'DIRS'` like this as well:
`'DIRS': [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates'))]`